# password toggle icon textinputlayout override error icon

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components, android-textinputedittext

I am using a password toggle to show and hide the password. And I do not want to use the custom drawable. But, when this edit text generate error it overrides the toggle password icon and unable to add padding or margin to that icon. If there is any solution to this, it will be a pleasure.
This is the code I am using:

```
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="40"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/app_green_color" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: android:backgroundTint="@color/white" remove this line

Comment: It is not so clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  you can see image in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc21z.jpg
I hope you will understand my question.

Comment: @SaadKhan Use the version 1.1.0 or later. The error icon appears and the password toggle icon disappears.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti using 1.1.0-beta01. but unable to solve this.

Comment: Use the com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText instead of EditText

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti using `com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0` nothing has change. The error icon still gets overlapped by password toggle.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS try this one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095321/10097307

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `TextInputEditText` instead of the `EditText`.

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
       app:endIconTint="@color/white"
       ...>

         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
           android:inputType="textPassword"
           ../>

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Also (but it is not related to the issue) the attributes `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` and `app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white"` are now deprecated. Use **`app:endIconMode`** and **`app:endIconTint`**.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I'm using TextInputLayout and

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

Any of the answers above didn't help me. This is the correct way to do it:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 ...
 app:errorIconDrawable="@null">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
     ...
     />
```

Comment: This is the answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the errorIconDrawable to null when you set the text error to something, so it won't override the toggle password icon.

Like this:

```
if (hasError) {
    textInputLayout.error = "Error text"
    textInputLayout.errorIconDrawable = null
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it.
Assign id to the textinputlayout and setError to textinputlayout, not edittext. Like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/tilSignUpPassword"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
  app:hintEnabled="false">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSignUpPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="#a3a1a1"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.09"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In Class:

```
 //your condition
 .....
 tilSignUpPassword.setError("Message")
 .....
```

Don't forget to setError(null) after your condition match.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095321/10097307